# How to filter taxonomy of a custom post type and display it in the single post type page in the back end?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type of products and I want to retrieve its taxonomy terms and display it in the backend. Am using  ACF for these tabs and would want to filter the **sizes** attributes dynamically and name it in the tab.

[image]

```
    $postID              =   get_the_ID();
    $have_terms          =   get_the_terms($postID, 'product_attributes');

    if($have_terms){
    $parent_terms  = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(),'product_attributes', array( 'parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'id', 'order' => 'DESC', 'hide_empty' => false ) );
```

This is the code in my template but I don't know how can I display it in the single product edit page.

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-load_field/

look at the load fields hooks, you are gonna have to hit that custom field when it loads on the backend and  change the tabs label based on the post id being currently loaded etc.

Comment: @Ideatron hey, I  make this work already but my problem now is that it's not saving. Like when I hit the update button and refreshed the page then all are gone.

Comment: add_filter( 'acf/update_value/name=FIELD_NAME_YOUR_UPDATING', 'your_function', 10, 3 );
function Your_function($value, $post_id, $field ){
// do something to modify the value
return $value;
}

Comment: where can I pull the $value data? You can check my code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028195/saving-acf-add-local-field-in-acf